# (python, tkinter, ttk, style) How to change the whole color of ttk.Button?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to make a button change the color.

Here is my code :

```
 root = tk.Tk()
 style = ttk.Style()
 style.configure("test.TButton", background="white", foreground="white")
 test_btn = ttk.Button(root, style="test.TButton")
 test_btn.pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

I want to change the whole color of button. but its ridge(or margin or little of little of part of button) has been changed.

I tried same approach to change the color on "ttk.Label". it works perfect.
Is there a way to change the whole color of "ttk.Button" ??

Specifially, I want to make a button with image and the other part of button transparent.
So, I want to match the other part with same color of background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer To Your Question is- There Is Now Way To Style A `ttk` button,

#### But You You Can Infinitely Style A Normal `tk.Button` like this-

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


test_btn = Button(root, text="YOUR TEXT IS HERE!", background='crimson', foreground='white', width=30, 
height=5, font=('Segoe UI', 40))
test_btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thx! I solved this problem changing the default theme(vista) to "default".